# Custom JavaScript Button that launches flow works for Admins only, not Users

Tags: visualforce, javascript, custom-button, opportunity

I am running a custom javascript button that launches a flow. I am able to get this to run as a Admin but not as a user. What Permissions should I check for to get this running for my users?

```
(function(){ 
    var bdEstPremAmntValid = Boolean("{!Opportunity.BD_Estimated_Premium_Amount__c}"); 
    var bdEstPremSrcValid = Boolean("{!Opportunity.BD_Estimated_Premium_Source__c}"); 

    if(bdEstPremAmntValid == true && bdEstPremSrcValid == false){ 
    alert("This opportunity cannot be marked followup complete until estimated premium source is filled out."); 
    return; 
    } 

    var win = window.open('/apex/FollowUpCompleteShell?opptyId={!Opportunity.Opportunity_ID__c}', 'windowName',"width=600,height=355"); 
    var timer = setInterval(function() { 
    if(win.closed) { 
    clearInterval(timer); 
    location.reload(); 
    } 
    }, 1000); 
})();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to verify the following:

1. The `User` you are testing with can see the fields in question, namely `BD_Estimated_Premium_Amount__c` and `BD_Estimated_Premium_Source__c`.
2. The `User` you are testing with must have access to the `Visualforce Page` in question, namely `FollowUpCompleteShell`. You can double-check which `Profiles` can access the page by going to `Setup` > `Develop` > `Visualforce Pages`. Find `FollowUpCompleteShell` and click the `Security` link next to it.

If the user already has access to those three things, we will need some sort of error message if we are to assist you.

Comment: Ok thanks, they did not have access to the visualforce page. Now the button works but it goes straight to the end of the flow. It just displays the Your Flow Has Finish. I have screens in the flow that requires input.

Comment: Hmm seems like a separate question than this one, which it seems I have solved?

Comment: Yes, you solved the intial question at hand. I have mark it solved. But I am still having problems with the flow not running properly. It works for Admins but not as a user.

Comment: Right, I think you should ask a separate question about that issue, into which I do not have much insight.